# how do i dynamically build fancybox gallery in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So i have this element on the page that when a user clicks on I would like to open into a fancybox gallery.. the elements on page are dynamically generated and the number of images in each album will differ.

I have an object called `imginfo` which holds the album information and image urls as well. `imginfo.url` where url is an array. looks like this..

`imginfo.url[0]='http://i.imgur.com/blah.jpg'`
`imginfo.url[1]='http://i.imgur.com/blah.jpg'` etc

my code

```
$('#clickbox').click(function() {
    var holderr = new Array();
    var mini = new Array();

    for(i=0;i<imginfo.album;i++){

        mini['href'] = imginfo.url[i];
        mini['title'] = 'title';
        holderr[i] = mini;
    }
    var h = JSON.stringify(holderr);                            
    $.fancybox([ 
        {href : imginfo.url[0], title : 'Title'},//this is the part that needs to dynamic that i dont know how to do
        {href : imginfo.url[1], title : 'Title'},
        {href : imginfo.url[2], title : 'Title'} 
        ]); 

}
```

So yea, having trouble generating the proper format for fancybox. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `imginfo` return? ... what do you use `holderr` and `mini` for? (and why `var h = JSON.stringify(holderr);`). I don't see how they are related to the fancybox gallery you want to build. I guess you would only need `imginfo.url` to build the proper format, unless I am missing something.

Comment: you are probably not missing anything, i am kidna grasphing at the moment. I probably don't need holderr or mini.. so how do would i get all the urls into the fancybox hrefs?

Comment: ... then, what does `imginfo.url` return? something like `'http://i.imgur.com/one.jpg','http://i.imgur.com/two.jpg', etc`?

Comment: yea.. but i tried just putting imginfo.url in the fancybox just as is and it didnt work.